# Dim outFileCTL As IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(filename,False) equivalent in C#

Tags: asp.net

Anyone help me VB.net code C# code.
Dim outFileCTL As IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(filename,False)

equivalent in C#

Answer (score 0):

vb.net has that built in "server" object - saves you have to define a stream writer.

So, this code would be the same in vb.net

```
    Dim fStream As StreamWriter

    fStream = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\test2\test.txt", False)

    fStream.WriteLine("First line of text")
    fStream.Close()

    ' above could also be

    Dim fStream2 As New StreamWriter("c:\test2\test.txt")

    fStream2.WriteLine("First line of text 22")
    fStream2.Close()
```

Thus in c#, use the 2nd approach, and thus we get this:

```
using System.IO;
.... etc.
```

And then

```
    StreamWriter fStream2 = New StreamWriter(@"c:\test2\test.txt");

    fStream2.WriteLine("First line of text 22");
    fStream2.Close();
```

Note that we placed a "@" in front of the string. We normal don't have to do this, but for strings with a "" in them, that has special meaning in c#, and thus the @ in front ignores that special meaning.